# Div para organizar checkbox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Tenho a seguinte `div`:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="checkbox"> Touch Screen
  <input type="checkbox"> Wi-fi
  <input type="checkbox"> Bluetooth
  <input type="checkbox"> Flash
  <input type="checkbox"> Câmera Frontal
  <input type="checkbox"> GPS
  <input type="checkbox"> Tecnologia NFC
  <input type="checkbox"> Extensão para Cartão de Memória
</div>
```

Ela fica assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas eu queria deixar ela assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve estar usando o Bootstrap, portanto deve recorrer ao sistema de Grid do próprio Bootstrap para realizar o trabalho de organização, veja o link http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Touch Screen </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Wi-fi </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Bluetooth </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Flash </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Câmera Frontal </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> GPS </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox"> Tecnologia NFC </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><input type="checkbox"> Extensão para Cartão de Memória </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja uma demostração: http://www.bootply.com/8bSBV6znyp

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou certinho!

Comment: Por nada @user13840, o importante é entender o conceito descrito na documentação, pegando o macete, vc vai longe.

Answer (score 0):

não sei se te ajuda muito, mas pode fazer isso do exemplo, mas lembrando que tem que tomar cuidado com o tamanho caso seja layout responsivo, mas creio que já lhe dará um caminho.

https://jsfiddle.net/spxdry2m/1/

Abraço.

Comment: Obrigado Angelo já me deu um norte.